# Кастомизация формы email Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите что я не так делаю. Мне нужно поправить файл 
`woocommerce/emails/plain/customer-new-account.php`

На почту приходит письмо, в котором ссылка на ЛК указана как текст, я хочу сделать кликабельной, добавив тег **a**

Исходный код:

`echo sprintf( __( 'You can access your account area to view your orders and change your password here: %s.', 'woocommerce' ), wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) . "\n\n";`

Мой код:

`echo sprintf( __( 'You can access your account area to view your orders and change your password here: <a href="%s">%s</a>.', 'woocommerce' ), wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) . "\n\n";`

Comment: Как в собираетесь послать html код `<a>...</a>` в plain text email? Это не работает в принципе.

Comment: понятно, я этого не знал, какие есть вариант?

Comment: Отправляйте html почту. Выберите настройку в WooCommerce и используйте файл `woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php` - без plain.

Comment: Спасибо, я не увидел что там есть 2 шаблона, 1 для HTML, второй для Plain Text. Еще и думал для чего это переключение в админке.

Comment: Еще один близкий вопрос. При регистрации письмо на мыло приходит, а если делаешь восстановление пароля, то письмо не приходит. В спаме тоже нет.

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Да, действительно все работает, только нужно было править в файле**

`woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php`

`<p><?php printf( __( 'Your password has been automatically generated: %s', '<p><?php printf( __( 'You can access your account area to manage your wishlist and change your password here: %s.', 'woocommerce' ), '<a href="' . wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) . '">' . wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) . '</a>'  ); ?></p>`